# apache dispatcher rewrite query string rule

Tags: regex, apache, dispatcher

I need to rewrite a URL with a query string into another URL.

For example, I have `https://www.something.com/cat/man/clothing/?colourfilter=blue_red`

It needs to be rewritten to `https://www.something.com/cat/man/clothing.html/colourfilter=blue_red`

I tried to follow the tutorial at https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

My current attempt is below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^colourfilter=([a-zA-Z][0-9]-*)$
RewriteRule ^(.)$ (.*).html/colourfilter=%1 [R302,L]
```

I cannot get it to work.

Comment: in fact, the project is java spring mvc based, just this part question is not quite 'java related'  i have removed java tag,  btw, Mandy8055's solution helps :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
(.*)\/\?(.*)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`(.*)`** - Represents first capturing group capturing the part of url before a query string leaving `\?`.
>
> **`\/\?(.*)`** - Represents a second capturing group capturing the query string part leaving the `\?`.
>
> **`$1.html/$2`** - `$1` represents the first captured group and `$2` the second captured group. If `$` doesn't work try replacing with `\\`. This will provide the necessary replacement.

[image: pictorial representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/78UGAg/7)

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteCond won't match on the correct query string, your regex now says it should match on any string starting with a letter a-z or A-Z, then a number, then possibly multiple times '-'. If you use https://regex101.com/ , you will notice that for example `colourfilter=a9------` matches your regex, which is not correct. You can use `^colourfilter=([a-zA-Z0-9]*_[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$` as regex, that should match your example and fulfill your needs, with this regex any query string starting with a couple of numbers/letters then an underscore and then again some numbers or letters will match.